# Undefined local variable or method when accessing from controller to helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a controller which called 'internal releases'.

I want to check that the multi-select objects contains at least one selection each.

In my controller I have:

```
class InternalReleasesController < ApplicationController

  def show

    if params[:run].nil?
      logger.error "Attempt to get trend result without going through the internal_releases_trend_selection_url"
      flash[:no_arguments] = 'You have tried accessing trend results without selecting parameters.'
      redirect_to internal_releases_trend_selection_url

    else 
      all_options = Array.new(params[:run][:category_id])
      missing_selections = validate_arguments params[:run]

      all_options = Array.[]params[:run][:category_id]

      logger.debug "all_options is: #{all_options.class}"
    end

  end
end
```

I created a simple helper method:

```
module InternalReleasesHelper

  def validate_arguments multiselect_hash

    answer = Array.new

    multiselect_arr.each do |key, val_arr|
      if val_arr.length==1  # therefore, no selection made in this multiselect- the first arg will always be ""
        answer << key
      end
    end
    answer
  end
end
```

For some reason I get:

```
undefined method `validate_arguments' for #<InternalReleasesController:0x007faf08bf9f78>
```

What might cause this?

Comment: Where do you bring in that module? Helpers are for the view layer unless you specifically make it available to the controller, no?

Comment: This module is placed at /app/helpers and was generated by rails when I issued the    `generate` command

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html - You need to make that helper available in the controller using the ``.helper`` method.

Comment: So if I wish to use a subroutine I should define it in the controller itself?

Comment: Or use the `helper` method as stated, or include it explicitly, or... The method's location depends on its utility and usage.

Comment: Great, thanks!
I'll stick with rails convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helper's method are just available into Views by default, so you should include your helper into controller:

Navigate on internal_releases_controller.rb file and insert following:

```
include InternalReleasesHelper
```

Answer (score 3):

Include helper module **InternalReleasesHelper** into **InternalReleasesController** class

```
class InternalReleasesController  
include InternalReleasesHelper  
end
```